# Migration from getCmp

Tags: extjs

I use `getCmp` wherever is possible in my application, but now I want to migrate from this poor-style programming to a better way of referencing elements. Imagine, I now have an element with `itemId` set to "myitemId" and I want to reference it from any part of the script, I do not want to use `up` or `down` methods, because I want to have a uniform way of referencing an element like `Ext.getCmp`. I tried to use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("myitemId")` and `Ext.query("#myitemId")` as an alternative to `Ext.getCmp("myitemId")`, but to no avail. So, what is the right method and right syntax to use?

**Edit**

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#myitemId")` also returns nothing.

PS. I use Extjs 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax to replace Ext.getCmp is: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myitemId')[0]`.

That said, simply replacing Ext.getCmp with Ext.ComponentQuery.query will not improve your code. In fact it will make it slower, because Ext.getCmp makes simple and fast hash lookups while Ext.ComponentQuery.query does Component tree traversal every time.

You should reconsider the whole approach. Looking up Components by id is not bad per se but it will make your code harder to maintain in the long run.

Comment: It works. As for speed, I mostly use Ext.getCmp in single-step operations and therefore I would hardly see any difference.